# How to use textures from GameTextures.com on Unity3D and Maya?

Tags: unity-game-engine, maya, texture-mapping

Each texture from gametextures.com came with a series of maps. But I don't know *exactly* where I need to put this maps in Maya and Unity.

- Diffuse map => this is easy, almost any unity shader have a diffuse field, and in Maya it is connected to the material's color
- Specular map => ?
- Gloss map => ?
- Normal Map => this is easy too, unity has normal fields in some shaders, and in Maya it is connected to the Bummped Mapping
- Transparency Map =>
- Height Map =>
- Emissive Map =>

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Maya, I got a response from gametexrures.com guys:

http://simplymaya.com/forum/showthread.php?t=40107

Answer (score 0):

It's going to vary based on the shader you pick.  For example, in a typical BumpedSpecular you'd need to copy a (grayscale) copy of the specular map into the alpha of the diffuse.  You will probably find more esoteric shaders that support, say, colored specular in the RGB channel and gloss map in the alpha of that.  For a transparent material you will probably have the transparency in the alpha of the diffuse map (pay close attention to the channel names in the inspector - they usually tell you what goes into the different channels of the texture)

Emissive applies to self illumination shaders, height to parallax, and gloss to shaders with per-pixel specular highlight control. Unity typically expects you to combine different aspects of these (such as diffuse in RGB and transparency or self-illum in A).  The derails are really up to the individual shaders. Default unity docs [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/Built-inShaderGuide.html) describe this in more detail.

Don't worry about the extra maps in Maya unless you need them while modeling. If you just put a diffuse on their to help you establish the registration between the textures and the model, you can apply the different maps in your Unity shaders. The Maya shader will not map exactly on to any of the Unity shader sets, so unless you need to check the registration (is, you'd like to see proper transparency on a model that has a transparency textures) don't waste energy hooking up one setup in Maya and then creating a different one in Unity. The output medium (Unity) is the one that matters.